# I have trouble interpreting messages from the console using the tsung tool

Tags: testing, load, tsung

I'm doing some experiments to learn how to use the tsung tool. I have a doubt that may be stupid but that I would like to resolve. After launching the tool from ubuntu console, the following screen appears to me:
[image: This is the message i get]

what I would like to know is if the message is the one that comes out at the end of the test or if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have downloaded the `tsung-1.7.0.tar.gz` file(latest version) from [here](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/dist/tsung-1.7.0.tar.gz). Also you have follow the [installation process](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/installation.html) step by step including the dependencies.

1. As a first step, you have to open a terminal window and go to the path where `tsung-1.7.0` folder is available.
2. Then create a `config.xml` file (setting the file name is your wish)
3. Then use the command `tsung -f config.xml start`
4. As you see `Log directory` is created for the test run, you can copy & paste the path in a new terminal (for easy use). Run the `ls` command to view the files inside the directory. You can use `tail -f tsung.log` command to view the run time log for the test run.
5. Tsung automatically monitors the client machine's CPU & memory and that will get stopped once the test run is completed successfully which was displayed in the log below the created Log directory

**Note:** If you don't know how to create a new configuration file, you open the `Examples` folder inside the `tsung-1.7.0` path and sample files will be available there.

Let me know if you have any doubts!